# Launchd agent not starting

Tags: macos, daemon, agent, launchd

I'm attempting to write a `launchd agent` that runs a simple application for every user that logs in to the Mac OS X system.

I have created a file named `com.mycompany.myapp.plist` and placed it in `/Library/LaunchAgents`. The contents of that file are:

```
{
    LimitLoadToSessionType = "Aqua";
    StartInterval = 10;
    OnDemand = NO;
    KeepAlive = YES;
    RunAtLoad = YES;
    Label = "com.mycompany.myapp";
    Program = "/Users/thomi/myapp";
    ProgramArguments = (
        "/Users/thomi/myapp",
        "-l",
        "-d",
    );
}
```

Initially I didn't have the `StartInterval` key set, since I thought the agent would start automatically. The problem is that the agent does not start unless I manually issue the following two commands:

```
launchctl load -S Aqua -D all
launchctl start com.mycompany.myapp
```

Firther, when I run `launchctl list com.mycompany.myapp` I get the following output:

```
{
    "Label" = "com.mycompany.myapp";
    "LimitLoadToSessionType" = "System";
    "OnDemand" = true;
    "LastExitStatus" = 0;
    "TimeOut" = 30;
    "Program" = "/Users/thomi/myapp";
    ProgramArguments = (
        "/Users/thomi/myapp",
        "-l",
        "-d",
    );
};
```

Notice that the `LimitLoadToSessionType` parameter has changed.

Am I missing something here? Is there a different mechanism to start agents like this? Why has the `LimitLoadToSessionType` property changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem - apparently `launchd` doesn't work properly with the old-style `plist` files. It loads OK, but won't run anything. Re-creating the above file as a new-style `XML` file solved the issue.

Comment: Can you give an exapmle of the new Style XML file, I have the same issue

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it's the problem, but I think you shouldn't be specifying both OnDemand/RunAtLoad and KeepAlive together. As I understand the documentation, the KeepAlive key replaces the OnDemand/RunAtLoad combo.

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/technotes/tn2005/tn2083.html#SECCODINGRECOMMENDATIONS

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @Thomi but you should not use KeepAlive with OnDemand/RunAtLoad.